# Pushing Javascript to DIV Tag

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to output this twitter feed to a  tag in the right column, but I can't figure out how to make it work. It seems like the code is set up to print wherever it is located. However, I can't place the code in the body of the page.

http://cusli.org/NiagaraIntlMootCourt/NiagaraMoot.aspx

Here is the code. I have a div tag with id "comments" in the html body.

```
<script charset="utf-8" src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#nav {
padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 760px;
    height: 0px;
    background:#6E102B;
    margin-bottom: 5px;

    }
.twtr-hd, 
.twtr-ft,
.twtr-user
{ 
display: none; 
}
</style>

<script>
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'profile',
  rpp: 4,
  interval: 30000,
  width: 250,
  height: 300,

  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#ffffff',
      color: '#000000'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#ffffff',
      color: '#000000',
      links: '#b80b0b'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: false,
    live: false,
    behavior: 'all'

  }


}).render().setUser('NiagaraMoot').start();

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div id="contentRight">

    <!-- this is your right coulmn, put TWitter script here -->
    <div class="myTwitter">
      <script>
         new TWTR.Widget({
           version: 2,

           ....

         }).render().setUser('NiagaraMoot').start();
      </script>
    </div> 
    <!-- end of your insert --> 

    <div id="dnn_ContentPane_Right">
     ....
```

CSS and main Tweeter JS library should stay in `<head> ... </head>` tag of you page - prefferably ... if you can not place them there ... they can be anywhere in your page but just before the init part (shown above).
I meen this part:

```
<script charset="utf-8" src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#nav {
padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 760px;
    height: 0px;
    background:#6E102B;
    margin-bottom: 5px;

    }
.twtr-hd, 
.twtr-ft,
.twtr-user
{ 
display: none; 
}
</style>
```

Comment: Is there a way to take the javascript that you suggest placing in the right frame and putting it in the header? Then push it to the DIV tag with a document.getelementbyid type of function?

Comment: Yes there is, but if you have access to your page  just put Twitter init code in your Right Hand Panel. Otherwise you can move it like this `$(function(){ $('#contentRight').prepend($('.myTwitter')); });` using jQuery. It could be done using pure Javscript of course but will more code should be done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script charset="utf-8" src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#nav {
padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 760px;
    height: 0px;
    background:#6E102B;
    margin-bottom: 5px;

    }
.twtr-hd, 
.twtr-ft,
.twtr-user
{ 
display: none; 
}
</style>

<script>
var myThing = new TWTR.Widget({ //save you reference
  version: 2,
  type: 'profile',
  rpp: 4,
  interval: 30000,
  width: 250,
  height: 300,

  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#ffffff',
      color: '#000000'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#ffffff',
      color: '#000000',
      links: '#b80b0b'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: false,
    live: false,
    behavior: 'all'

  }


}); //remove from here

</script>
```

inside your HTML go

```
<div>
<script>
myThing.render().setUser('NiagaraMoot').start(); //add here
</script>

</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that I can't place javascript in the body of the page, only in the header. It's a CMS restriction with DotNuke.

Answer (score 0):

Put the script tag inside the div where you want it to render.

eg:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello world</h2>
    <div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        new TWTR.Widget({
          version: 2,
          type: 'profile',
          rpp: 4,
          interval: 30000,
          width: 250,
          height: 300,

          theme: {
            shell: {
              background: '#ffffff',
              color: '#000000'
            },
          tweets: {
            background: '#ffffff',
            color: '#000000',
            links: '#b80b0b'
          }
         },
         features: {
           scrollbar: false,
           loop: false,
           live: false,
           behavior: 'all'    
         }        
         }).render().setUser('NiagaraMoot').start();
      </script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So the reason I want to push the content to a DIV tag is that I cannot place javascript in the body of my page. I have to keep all the code in the header.